# Preencher useState com array de objetos

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

Estou estudando React Native e estou construindo um aplicativo como demo para a empresa em que trabalho, neste app existe uma etapa que tenho que preencher um useState array com os valores de outro array obtido do armazenamento local através do AsyncStorage, só que este outro array esta preenchido com objetos. Como posso preencher o useState com esses valores do array secundário? pois mesmo quando tento preencher os dados o array do useState sempre volta vazio

```
//useState que estou querendo peencher
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getTableData = async () => {
      try {
        //obtenho os dados locais e transfomo em um array
        const objTableData = JSON.parse(
          await AsyncStorage.getItem('rdoNotSent'),
        );
        if (objTableData) {

          //tento preencher o useState com os valores obtidos do AsyncStorage
          setTableData(...objTableData);

          //mesmo após todo o processo o valor ainda volta como 0
          console.log(tableData.length)
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(
          'Erro inesperado',
          'Ocoreu um erro ao carregar dados iniciais',
        );
      }
    };
    getTableData();
  }, []);
```

exemplo de array retornado pelo AsyncStorage

```
const arraySecundario = [
  {
    nome: 'joel',
    idade: 18,
  },
  {
    nome: 'maria',
    idade: 21,
  },
  {
    nome: 'eduardo',
    idade: 45,
  },
  {
    nome: 'pedro',
    idade: 32,
  },
];
```

obs: ao gravar o array no armazenamento interno do dispositivo tenho que converte-lo em string usando `JSON.stringify`, depois para obter os dados do dispositivo converto o mesmo para array novamente usando o `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente sua expectativa não está alinhada com seu código. Você está armazenando o array na constante *objTableData*, e logo depois joga o valor dessa constante no estado utilizando o spread operator conforme na linha:

```
setTableData(...objTableData);
```

Pra deixar bem claro pra você, seu resultado com essa escrita de código, deixaria o valor armazenado em memória/tempo de execução do seu estado semelhante a essa declaração:

```
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState({ nome: 'joel', idade: 18 });
```

Pois com o uso do spread operator em um array da forma que você fez, ele jogaria somente o primeiro objeto dentro do *tableData*, logo o console no *tableData.length* não traria o resultado esperado de maneira alguma pois a partir desta linha ele seria do tipo Object e não do tipo Array (Lembrando que o JS não é fortemente tipado e permite isso).

De acordo com sua expectativa escrita, seu código não deveria usar o spread operator pra enviar o array pro estado, ficando dessa forma:

```
setTableData(objTableData);
```

Qualquer dúvida, dá uma olhada no código que fiz de exemplo da sua situação no codesandbox, é só [clicar aqui](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-browser-s0ju0?file=/src/App.js).

Recomendo você dar uma estudada em como funciona o spread operator e em como funciona o useState. Aparentemente você imaginou que declarando o estado inicial com um array vazio ele iria jogar seus vários objetos dentro desse array mas não é bem esse o funcionamento.

Abraço!